# Converting a Time Punch to a Decimal

Tags: time

What formula would I use to convert a time punch of 69 hours and 42 minutes into a decimal? I would enter 69.42 in the cell and want it to convert to 69.7.

Comment: Why don't you just divide the number of minutes by 60?  You can then add that value to the number of hours worked.

Comment: https://www.exceltip.com/excel-date-time-formulas/convert-number-of-minutes-to-hours-and-minutesin-microsoft-excel-2010-2013.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem with what you're trying to do is you're using two different units of measurement (Minutes & Hours) - You have to pick one.

Minutes Formula:

HR*60 + Min
(ie 69*60+42 = 4182 Minutes)

Hours Formula:

HR + Min/60
(ie 69+42/60 = 69.7 Hours)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you type 69.42 into cell A1.

In cell B1 you can then type the formula

```
=INT(A1) + (A1-INT(A1))*100/60
```

It takes the integer part (the minutes) as they are (with `INT(A1)`), and then adds the part after the decimal point converted from minutes to the proper fraction of an hour. You can use `MOD(A1, 1)` instead of `(A1-INT(A1))` if you like.

You then copy the formula down into further cells as usual.

Here is a screenshot from a Danish version of Excel, so please ignore that the decimal points are commas. It still works in any version of Excel:

[image]

If you set up formatting to two decimals in column A and B, you get this:

[image]

In your further calculations you simply use the values in column B instead of the typed-in values in column A. So column A will be the column you type data into, and column B will be the column you make further calculations from.